# Form hangs while waiting on input

Tags: winforms, credit-card

I have written a custom point of sale system for our company. I have everything working, but found a small bug. After all the items have been added to the sale when they hit the "Credit" button it opens a credit card processing corm and has a function that listens for a card swipe. After it is swiped it fills in all the fields and asks for the CVV number then they hit process button and it's over.

The issue is say they "Accidentally" hit credit. The program freezes waiting for a card swipe. The close window button and everything doesn't respond to input. I am wanting a way to have the function that listens for the card run, but lets everything else proceed as well. My listener method is below.

```
Private Sub LoadCardReader()
    Timer1.Stop()
    If IsNothing(_Device) Then
        _Device = HidDevices.Enumerate(2049, 2).FirstOrDefault()
    End If

    _Device.OpenDevice()
    _Device.MonitorDeviceEvents = True
    Dim report As HidReport = _Device.ReadReport() 'This is where it hangs'
    ParseReport(report)
End Sub
```

I approached this from another avenue and have it working. I wrote a windows application that I call when the POS starts. It does nothing but listen for a card swipe then writes it to a text file. Then I put a timer on the POS that looks to see if the text file exists. If it does  it reads the data parses it then deletes the file so it will not pick it up again. Anyone see an issue with that?

Comment: you have to do multi-thread programming if you want the form to be responsive while waiting for input

Comment: Yeah I looked into the Multi-Threading but I couldn't see how to send the data from the credit card entry back to the main POS after completing the charge.

Comment: Multi-threading is more complicated then you thought, normally you can't just move from a sub thread back into the main thread. Can you be more specific on what you would like to do with the data?

Comment: Use the form's BeginInvoke() method.  It isn't very clear what class you are using but if I guessed right then you probably ought to consider the ReadReport() overload that takes the ReadReportCallback delegate argument.  Should be a non-blocking call.

Comment: *Anyone see an issue with that?* You really **really** need to take a look at PCI-DSS (and PA-DSS) It amazes me that you've got this far without being aware of it?